# Bigquery tables get data API returning Access Denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam, row-level-security

Not able to get the BQ get table data API work with row level policies.

Trying to make a HTTP API call to:
`https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project-name>/datasets/<dataset-name>/tables/<table-name>/data`.

I have authenticated using a OAuth2 acccess token.

I am getting error:
`Access Denied: Table <table-name>: User does not have full access for table <table-name> due to row access policies.`

Row level security policy have been defined for my user on the table. How can I make the above API call work with row level security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [TRUE filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-row-level-security-with-features#the_true_filter) on your row filtering definition.

Comment: But adding a `TRUE` filter would bypass row level security, no?

Comment: Yes for non query operation

Comment: Is there a way where I don't have to provide `TRUE filter` and make bigquery tables getData API to work?

Comment: According to the documentation, no.